# Django postgres migrate models column discount.category_name_id does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm, migrate

Hi i'm trying to combine Django backend and postgresql database together.

**Here is my database tables:**

[image: tables]

**My models.py in Django**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Categories(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField(null=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Website(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    site = models.TextField(null=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table= 'website'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.site

class Discount(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    product_name = models.TextField()
    product_price = models.TextField()
    product_old_price = models.TextField()
    product_link = models.TextField()
    category_name = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, to_field='name')
    product_site = models.ForeignKey(Website, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, to_field='site')
    product_image = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'discount'

    def __str__(self):
            return self.product_name
```

I managed to link Django and postgresql together following tutorials but when i try to migrate the database for the first time it come with this error :

> column discount.category_name_id does not exist LINE 1:
>   ..."."product_old_price", "discount"."product_link", "discount"...
>                                                                ^ HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "discount.category_name".

i though i linked my foreign key from discount.category_name to categories.name with to_field='name' in the ForeignKeyField but somehow it used the discount.category_name_id ? i don't know where the category_name_id is, it's not in my tables

Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: Don't create tables manually; let the ORM do that with `makemigrations` and `migrate`. There are some cases where you would want to do this, but this doesn't look like one of them, and it doesn't seem like it's something you've done a lot. Also, if a tutorial had you doing this... find another one. The [official one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/) is a good place to start.

Comment: Your schema is wrong anyway - category.name is not unique, so the discount table should reference category.id.

Comment: Thank for the advices i didn't create tables manually.I used a premade tables in postgres database and try to merge postgres database and django data so django can use postgresql as a database.After i connect them through settings.py it worked when i don't use foreign to connect table. Django need ORM in models to represent data in postgresql so i try to migrate it after makemigrations

Comment: Wait i think i had a mistake with manually create it, but i need to see my datas from postgres in django admin views(django admin view need models so i create the models ) and this seems to worked until i add foreign key constrain to tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fixed it by adding

> db_column='category_name'

to the ForeignKey field

It seems that i need to specific what column that actually is a Foreign key in my Postgresql tables to the ORM

```
category_name = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, to_field='name', db_column='category_name')
    product_site = models.ForeignKey(Website, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, to_field='site', db_column='product_site')
```

Answer (score 1):

Below field is not reflected in the database, please check you db fields name if not then create the one dummy migration and write the script for that

```
    category_name = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, to_field='name')
```